# How to show the file size which failed to upload in ng-file-upload?

Tags: ng-file-upload

The ng-file-upload documentation shows [samples of usage](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#usage). The first [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/38/) displays a validation message for file size:

```
<input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file"    
             accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required>
      <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i><br>
      <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.maxSize">File too large 
          {{picFile.size / 1000000|number:1}}MB: max 2M</i>
```

However, when I run the fiddle and upload a file larger than 2M, the validation message says:

```
File too large MB: max 2M
```

So the expression `{{picFile.size / 1000000|number:1}}` is absent from the message. It looks like `picFile.size` is not set. Is there a way to show the size?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Updated the sample page: http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/544/

You can use `ngf-model-invalid="errorFiles"` and then get the invalid file size by `errorFiles[0].size`.